# How do i put a vector into my arrayadapter?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-arrayadapter

I have the current code:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        colourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How would i put a vector into my array_spinner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vector class is considered deprecated, don't use it. Use a List instead. Then you can use the overloaded ArrayAdapter constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```